# What is an 'appropriate number' of 'significant foes' for the purposes of Never Conquered, Never Feared?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, optional-rules

So, I'm giving the players in my campaign a free Story Feat because I think they're cool from a hand-curated list of choices that they and I feel are appropriate to their characters backgrounds and their motivations.

One of my players has chosen the feat 'Never Conquered, Never Feared' from the AP War of the Crown, which states as its goal:

> You must individually slay an appropriate number of significant foes in succession, without retreating or withdrawing from a fight.

I'm trying to figure out exactly how to interpret this and would welcome some other peoples' opinions. Looking at the rules for story feats an 'Appropriate Number' of foes is defined as:

> These are either creatures whose individual CRs add up to 20, or creatures whose individual CRs add up to 5 times your character level, whichever is greater.

But these rules also define a 'Challenging Foe' as:

> This is a foe or group of foes with a total CR of 10 or a CR of 3 plus your character level, whichever is higher.

However, the feat's wording does not state 'Challenging Foes' but 'significant foes', so can I assume the definition of a Challenging Foe does not apply?

Also, would I be correct in assuming that 'individually slay' means 'by yourself, with no help'?

Answer (score 2):

### What these feats really mean is: it's up to you as the DM to determine what counts as an appropriate challenge.

What counts as a "significant foe" can vary wildly based on character build and owned magic items. A level 8 sorcerer could be a deadly encounter for a level 20 fighter if they don't have the right magic items to counter. One cast each of *Fly* and *Greater Invisibility* and the fighter has no hope of winning without some extraordinary luck or some specific magic items. Meanwhile, if the fighter has a Helm of See Invisibility and any ranged weapon, the difficulty is going to flip the other way.

You'll have to look at the players build and figure out what's good against it specifically.

And yes, "individually slay" in this case would mean that the person who possesses the feat must defeat the foes by themselves.

Comment: Except Story feats have explicit definitions of terms like 'appropriate number' and 'challenging foe' as I quoted in my question.

Comment: @Balfuset790 I'm only referring to the "significant foe" portion. The "Appropriate Number", being already defined, just means that they have to do it that many times. So a 1 vs [X] fight with all the enemies at once, or a 1 vs 1 [X] number of times, however you like.

Comment: @Balfuset790 Just because the designers opted to provide a definition for "challenging foe" does not require them to specify a definition for "significant foe" rather than simply leaving it up to the DM.